# How can I create a logo in LaunchScreen.storyboard?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have added an ImageView to my LaunchScreen.storyboard in Xcode 13.1 and I have selected my logo but I don't know what to do so that my logo is always in the center of the screen. What can I do so that my logo is always in the center of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open `LaunchScreen.Storyboard` with Xcode  .
2. Set constraints on the `ImageView`to determine its position and size .
3. Enable the options to let it centers in horizontally and vertically .

   [image]
4. Drag the square handle to the superview(Container) ,and make them Width/Height eqaul.

   [image]
5. Select property menu and modify the Width/Height to make them proportional to superView .

   [image]
6. Modify the multiplier to what you want(If the image is full with screen ,set it as 1) .

   [image]
7. Save and exit Xcode .

#### Update

The default content mode is `Aspect fit` , change it to `Scale To Fill`.

[image]

Refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/designer-auto-layout.

Comment: Where can I find the menu with Equal Widths and Equal Heights(from 4.)? I can not find this menu in Xcode. How can I create the constraints Proportional With to: Superview and Proportional Height to: Superview? I only have the following constraints: https://imgur.com/3Amq6y2

Comment: Hover your mouse on the image , keep pressing  `ctrl` and drag the image to the superview ,then the menu will appear.

Comment: I have found the menu and I have chosen Equal Widths and Equal Heights. But I'm not sure if I did everything correct because the size of my UIImageView is bigger than my .png image. My .png image has this size: 320x480 pixel. Does it matter if the UIImageView has not exactly the same size as my .png image or should I create a .png image with a different size? My launch screen in Xcode: https://imgur.com/kw3KsH2

Comment: Check my update .

Comment: My image gets distorted if I change the content mode from Aspect fit to Scale To Fill. Is it possible to change the UIImageView's width and height to the image's width and height? Does it matter if the UIImageView doesn't have the same size than my image?

Comment: If you want the image has the same size with UIImageView,  you need to make sure their ratio is same .

Comment: Thanx. It works now.